# Will GRUB handle my plan nominally?

Tags: dual-boot

Scenario: I've just done a major hardware upgrade from Zen 2 to Zen 3, including a new M.2 NVMe drive. My original NVMe/spinner combo is still handling the system; the new drive is visible in GParted but I've done nothing with it yet. This all is quite stable running 20.04LTS as we speak, on the original install.

What I propose: I'm disconcerted by the lack of temperature monitoring for my Ryzen 5800X. I propose to install a second Ubuntu instance fresh on the new M.2, which is to ultimately be the primary and only drive in the system (2TB 970 Evo+, sufficient for my storage needs when factoring the cloud and appropriate backup discipline). Wishing to do the 5.12 kernel - on whatever Ubuntu version, probably 21.04 - as it appears I can have that temperature monitoring with that kernel.

Who I am: I predate "Windows" at the keyboard - no stranger to command-line DOS, I come from there - but am getting old and cannot be arsed to use Terminal unless I have to. Have used Linux exclusively at home for 4 years, very happy with it for my needs (except for Pulse Audio but I'm sure you're already aware of that and 20.04 seems to have fixed it).

What I want: A successful dual-boot system while I play with the new instance to ensure it does what I wish it to. Not concerned with cloning because I use relatively few apps and only need to migrate data using standard file management.

My question: Will GRUB pick this up and run with it, offering me a dual-boot option, and if it all works will GRUB gracefully handle the removal of the original boot drive? I really want to keep things as uncomplicated as possible, and avoid other boot managers, although I will if necessary.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert but I ran into a slighty different scenario that I was able to fix. I had an older PC that I added an NVMe drive too. I would not boot the NVMe so I put in a small sata ssd and made that my /boot (EFI) partition. This worked well until I upgraded the PC. Removing the sata drive made my PC not boot. So I created a partition on my NVMe to be the new boot EFI partition and installed Grub there. It's been a few months but it did work.

Basic steps taken: move sata and NVMe drive to new PC, create new boot partition using gparted and mark it bootable, copied the contents of the sata drive to the NVMe boot partition, installed Grub to NVMe boot partition, removed sata and configured the bios to boot to the NVMe.

You will need to search how to move or install grub to other partitions as I forget how I did it. But this is the same concept essentially of what you are trying to do: move your grub install to a new drive.

I think you can also use grub-customizer and do some editing to point grub to the right UUID location for vmlinuz ie "set-root=..." and "root=UUID=..." in the grub config file before removing the current boot drive.

Comment: Even when this is possible, you should not migrate (copy) a installed operating system from SATA drive to modern PCIexpress SSD drive, because you'll have some performance issues with drive speed and your SSD drive will "wear out" faster, because it's insufficient configured.

Comment: @paladin that is not what I did. I used the ssd only for a boot partition as a stop gap measure. The OS was installed on the NVMe and recognized by ubuntu as such. NVMe mounted at / ssd mounted at /boot

Comment: You used the "old bootloader" of your old SSD on your new SSD (you copied the data) without reconfiguring, which might work, but also might crash your system. You were just lucky. It's not a very clean type of install.

Comment: @paladin I agree I was lucky. But in this case the OP will be using an NVMe bootloader from the start. I simply shared my experience to show that it is indeed possible.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution will be:

- touch nothing of your previous system
- just regulary install Ubuntu onto your new SSD drive
- select your new SSD drive as boot drive in your BIOS/UEFI

Your new system should boot.

When you have removed/formatted your old Linux drive and you wish to remove the now outdated grub-boot option for that now gone Linux, just type *"sudo update-grub"* in a terminal.

The command *"update-grub"* searches all attached drives for bootable operating systems and creates/modifies the grub-boot-screen to the current state of existing bootable operating systems. (a very handy command)